# React Server Side Rendering App - how to update meta data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am currently building a react app and am having a few issues...

I have configured the server side rendering of my page using the following code...

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/homepage', (req, res) => {
    match({routes, location: req.originalUrl}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if(!err) {
            const html = this.render(renderProps);
            const data = {};

            res.render('index', {
                content: html,
                context: data,
                pageTitle: 'Homepage Title'
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).send();
        }
    });
});

router.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    match({routes, location: req.originalUrl}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if(!err) {
            const html = this.render(renderProps);
            const data = {};

            res.render('index', {
                content: html,
                context: data,
                pageTitle: 'Contact Us'
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).send();
        }
    });
});

return router;
```

where 'index' is the name of my view...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico?v=004" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>{{{pageTitle}}}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ui-role="content">{{{content}}}</div>
    <script>window.APP_STATE = {{{context}}};</script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js" defer></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/1.0.0/ReactRouter.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/1.12.6/History.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/<version>/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The pageTitle renders correctly if I navigate to the two separate pages individually, but when if I anchor from one page to another (i.e. using `<a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>`) the pageTitle on the client will not change and will still show 'Homepage Title'

How can I ensure the pageTitle changes on the client?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your OP, but you might want to consider a generic route on the server for all requests to allow for react-router to work more simply. `router.get('/*', (req, res) => { match(.... }`

Comment: I did consider this, but I thought I'd still need to serve up the page title from the server and so wasn't able to make it generic. Now that your answer works i should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do client side navigation you'll need to manually update the title of the page using `document.title`. The server will only inject the title when you make fresh page requests.

Let's say this is the Contact component...

```js
class Contact extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // this only executes on the browser, not server
    document.title = 'Contact Page';
  }
  
  // you could also use this to inject props
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    document.title = `Contact Page - ${nextProps.someValue}`;
  }
  
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

There are also open source components that can do this for you, like [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title).

Comment: Thanks very much!